# C++ If statement causes CMD to not post output?

Tags: c++

I made a BMI calc in C++, and decided I'd want to add a portion that calculates a users new BMI given a weight change weekly(say, losing 2 pounds every week, or gaining 2 pounds every week, for n weeks) I have two if statements set up, so that when asked what weight change they were looking for, based on that result it would jump to one if statement or the other. What I mean, is that if the user wants to **LOSE** weight, they would put -2, which would jump to the if statement I have setup for losing weight. If a user wanted to **GAIN** weight, it would jump to another if statement, set up to calculate the new BMI given the new weight change. Here are my two if statements setup:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> // Allows us to use cout and cin
#include <cmath> // To allow us to calculate the BMI
#include <iomanip> // Set specific decimal points(two)
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double weight;
cout << "What is your current weight?: "; // Using the cout() function, we get user input
cin >> weight;
double heightFeet;
cout << "What is your height(in feet, just the first part(Example, if you're 5'11, put 5)";
cin >> heightFeet;
double heightInches;
cout << "What is your height in inches, just the second part(Example if you're 5'11, put 11)\n";
cin >> heightInches;
double HeightConverter = 12 * heightFeet + heightInches;
cout << "Your height in inches is: " << HeightConverter << "\n";
double BMICalc = (weight * 703) / (pow(HeightConverter, 2));
std::cout << std::fixed;
std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
std::cout << "Your current BMI is: " << BMICalc << "\n";
double GoalWeight;
std::cout << "What is your goal weight change per week? (lb)\n";
cin >> GoalWeight;
if (GoalWeight >= 0) {
    int weeks;
    cout << "How many weeks do you plan to continue this trend?\n";
    cin >> weeks;
    double PosBMI = (weight + GoalWeight) * 703 / (pow(HeightConverter, 2));
    cin >> PosBMI;
    cout << "If you complete your plan for " << weeks << "weeks you will have a new BMI of: \n" << PosBMI;

}
if (GoalWeight < 0) {
    int weeks;
    cout << "How many weeks do you plan to continue this trend?\n";
    cin >> weeks;
    double NegBMI = (weight - GoalWeight) * 703 / (pow(HeightConverter, 2));
    cin >> NegBMI;
    cout << "If you complete your plan for " << weeks << "weeks you will have a new BMI of: \n" << NegBMI;
}
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

When this is compiled, it gets to **"How many weeks do you plan to continue this trend?"**, if I put in 3, it pauses at 3 in the terminal, and does nothing, and eventually I have to just close it. Does anyone see what the issue is in the if statements? Sorry for the ugly code as well in advance. Bear with me here.

Answer (score 1):

Big problem with PosBMI being declared and initialized then immediately overwritten by std::cin call.  Analogous problem in NegBMI.

```
double PosBMI = (weight + GoalWeight) * 703 / (pow(HeightConverter, 2));
cin >> PosBMI;
```

Then of course, weight is not declared... I think that you need to get this to compile first.

All that said, I would like to add that my personal BMI needs work.

I imagine that your code more likely should be (pseudo-codish here)

```
cout << "Enter your weight";
cin >> weight;
cout << "Enter Goal"
cin >> WeightGoal

if (WeightGoal > weight) {
  .....
} else {
  ....
}
cout << "If you complete your plan for " << weeks << .....
```

Comment: Should I add each std::cin call into their respected if statements? I would assume I'd still need both? Or do I only need ONE cin statement?

Comment: weight is declared actually, it's just omitted from the code in the OP, it was just for calculating the original BMI, it should still be able to be accessed out of the scope if it's a global variable, right?

Comment: I think that you only want to ask once.   And I believe that your GoalWeight is really a case of "weight > GoalWeight" and vice versa.

Comment: I already ask for the weight at the beginning, i'm updating the OP with the entire code so you can see where I'm going/went with this, and hopefully helps you and I! :)